# how to set sequalize postgres model type for inet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am using [sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/) ORM to manage postgress database.

In my postgress database we use a datatype [inet](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-net-types.html) to store the IPv4, IPv6 values.

As I was creating the models in sequalize, I was not able to find the `inet` type in sequelize.

What can I use instead of `inet` in sequelize to create the model?

```
const User = sequelize.define(
  'User',
  {
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,  /*postgres varchar data type*/
      unique: true,
    },
    encrypted_password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,  /*postgres varchar data type*/
      allowNull: false,
    },
    last_login_ip: {
      type:  ?,   /*postgres inet data type*/
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is support for INET Datatype for the newer versions(Be careful it is only available for Postgres).
https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js~INET.html

```
const User = sequelize.define(
  'User',
  {
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,  /*postgres varchar data type*/
      unique: true,
    },
    encrypted_password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,  /*postgres varchar data type*/
      allowNull: false,
    },
    last_login_ip: {
      type: Sequelize.INET,   /*postgres inet data type*/
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of sequelize has support for INET data type.  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/data-types.html